# How can I upload a KML file to a website for an organization with multiple locations?

Tags: kml

I am trying to update a KML file for a website that has a multiple locations and having some trouble. I want to use it accordance with schema.org to get rich snippets in Google search results. My problem is I can't find a solid answer on how to relate multiple listings to the proper pages.

I think I understand how to create the KML file from these resources.

- https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut
- http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/5-little-known-web-files-that-can-enhance-your-website/

Here is my example code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <Document>
  <name>Hospital 1</name>
  <description>Our first hospital</description>
  <Style id="pin"><IconStyle><Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href></Icon></IconStyle></Style>
  <Placemark>
    <LookAt>
      <longitude>-0.13642</longitude>
      <latitude>50.819522</latitude>
      <altitude>0</altitude>
      <tilt>0</tilt>
      <range>5500</range>
    </LookAt>
    <styleUrl>#pin</styleUrl>
    <Point><coordinates>-0.13642,50.819522,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  </Document>
  </kml>
```

I know that it has to be in the root folder and named after the site. But how do I name different locations or associate them to a certain page? Can I put the kml file on the different location pages?

I might be thinking about this in the wrong way so any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sixrevisions.com link, the part you are missing is that you have to reference this KML file on your webpage with a `LINK` tag:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" href="SixRevisions.kml" />
```

The location and name of the file aren't important (as long as you update the `href` attribute).  You can put this tag on whatever page you want so you can point each page at a separate file.

Comment: Thank you, David. That makes sense. I just want to confirm that we are to have a separate KML for each location. Once the files are uploaded, we are to link to the corresponding KML file from the landing page associated with that location.

Comment: I don't have proof of this, but if a web page deals with multiple locations, I would expect the KML file to contain multiple locations as well.

Comment: Hi David, thank you again. There are individual web pages for each location. For exmaple www.hospital.com/location-x/ and www.hospital.com/location-y/ I guess what I am trying to figure out is if I can create one KML file and attribute the specific location X landing page with a particular part of the KML file and attribute the specific location y page with a particular part of the KML file or if I should create a separate KML file for each location and refer to it in the corresponding landing page with the LINK tag. I hope that makes sense. I really appreciate your insight here.

Comment: If you use the `link` tag to associate a KML file with a web page, then the entire KML file is used.  You can't link a subset of a KML file to a web page.  So in your case I would create a separate KML file for each location.

Comment: Okay, great! Thank you so much for all of your help here. I really appreciate it.